# Knockout Databind Event Fires twice

Tags: knockout.js

Im Rendering a Option Select including an Change Event. After Rendering the Event fires twice... i cant figure why...

```
  <select id="@Model.ID)" 
          data-bind = "@string.Format("
          options: groupItems({0}), 
          optionsText : 'description',  
          optionsValue : 'id', 
          optionsAfterRender: afterDropDownRender, 
          value : selectedItem({0}),  
          event: {{ change: selectionChanged }}", Model.GroupID)"></select>
```

The Event "selectionChanged" is fireing twice after changeing a selection.

Comment: Could you provide some more info? What does the HTML rendered on the client look like? Are you using computed observables?

Comment: You are using ASP.NET with Razor, right?

Comment: Sorskoot, Im using MVC and Razor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out what is rendered on the client. It should look something like:

```
<select id="IdFromServer" data-bind = "options: groupItems(2),                     
          optionsText: 'description',   
          optionsValue : 'id',                
          value : selectedItem(2),  
          event: { change: selectionChanged }"></select>
```

---

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BF7R5/7/)

Comment: Rendered is this:
            <select id="cb_group_1133" name="cb_group_1133"
                    data-bind = "options: groupItems(1133), optionsText : &#39;description&#39;,  optionsValue : &#39;id&#39;, optionsAfterRender: afterDropDownRender, value : selectedItem(1133),  event: { change: selectionChanged }"
                    data-groupid =  "1133"
                    data-packageid = "1130"
                    data-pageid = "91"
                    data-hasperiod="True"
                    
                >
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not quite right. You just need to bind options to groupItems and not `groupItems({0})`. Same goes for selected Item. The resulting html should be:

```
<select data-bind ="options: groupItems, 
          optionsText : 'description',  
          optionsValue : 'id', 
          optionsAfterRender: afterDropDownRender, 
          value : selectedItem,  
          event: { change: selectionChanged }"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXMv5/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the cause, although not quite clear why..

when Drilling down and left out

```
value: selectedItem(2),
```

the Event doesnt fire twice..

no diving into "selectedItem" :)